# lost my phone .bought new phone got same number.how do i get my contacts

Tags: data-recovery

I lost my phone LG34 today. I've purchased a new phone and had the data restored but I don't know how to retrieve my contacts.

I'm not too bright with computers so please explain in simple terms how I can restore my contacts.

Comment: Login to your Google account and turn ON the "Auto Sync". All the previous data including Contacts, Calendar, etc must restore.

Comment: You should be able to track your phone with android device manager. PS: login with the same Google account as on your lg34.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the contacts were synced with Google or any other means, they are lost.

Comment: but if the contacts were synced then he could be able to recover them.

Comment: true that, but the OP didn't mention anything about if they were synced or not.

So basically it's an incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone was synched with a Google account, you can go to `Settings > Accounts` (that may vary on devices) and sync with google, after a few moments, your contacts (and various other stuff) should come back.